# Does CloudFoundry provide Application-as-a-Service?

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry, paas

I'm looking for a cloud-based (pub, priv or hybrid) solution that allows me to configure every detail about the platform (container, system stack, virtualized hardware, etc.) for my app, but also **deploys a templated version of my app on all app server nodes** as soon as I run my 1st build. Hence I configure the app/platform, click a button, and boom: I have a WAR deployed and running across a cluster of nodes. (Granted, since I have not written any code at this point, this deployed WAR would have de minimis code inside of it and would consistitute the bare minimal code required to produce a WAR. In the case of Grails, it might just be the code that is generated by running `grails create-app myapp`.)

I'm calling this "Application-as-a-Service", because it not only is a traditional PaaS, but also goes one step further and deploys packaged WARs using some kind of templated source code repo.

My question: CloudFoundry says they support multiple frameworks (Spring, Grails, etc.); does this mean it can do what I describe above? If not, what does CloudFoundry mean when they say that they "support the Grails framework"?

Answer (score 0):

Using CF you are able to configure platform/OS. Currently used container is warden. Virtualised hardware depends on IaaS used for(under) CF. Then you may 'click a button' and your app will be deployed and running across a cluster of nodes (DEA instances).

Answer (score 0):

> CloudFoundry says they support multiple frameworks (Spring, Grails, etc.); does this mean it can do what I describe above?

I don't fully follow what you're trying to do above, but I can tell you about the general work flows for CloudFoundry.

As an administrator, you use Bosh to deploy CloudFoundry to your IaaS.  You can control anything you want at the IaaS level (assuming you're an administrator for your IaaS), so long as you meed the requirements of CF like storage, memory and CPU.  In addition, you can control the CF deployment by adjusting the various configuration settings (YAML files) for CF.  This allows you to tune the amount of resources (memory, CPU, disk space, etc..) that are available for application developers.

As a developer, you take your application and push it to a running CF installation.  You may or may not be the administrator of that CF installation, if you are not then you'll be subject to the policies of the administrator.

The push process takes your application (ruby, python, php, go, java, grails, etc...) and uploads it to CF.  From there, the application files are turned into a droplet by the build pack.  This process is easier than it sounds, the build pack is just adding all the things that are necessary to run your app, like a web server or app container.  With the droplet created, CF will run it or possibly even multiple instances of it if you so desire.

A couple further notes / clarifications:

- How much memory your application gets is up to the app developer and can be adjusted at the time an app is push or later using `cf scale`.
- CPUs are shared across all apps.  You cannot reserve or guarantee usage per app.  Application usage is limited though, so one app cannot steal all of the available CPUs.
- The amount of disk storage per app is set by the administrator.
- Disk storage for applications is ephemeral and is cleared when an application is restarted.  Persistent storage should be provided through a service.

As you can see, CF administrators have a good degree of control over the system.  Application developers not so much, but that is in fact the point of PaaS.  Application developers don't want to waste time playing sys-admin.  They just want to run their apps.

> If not, what does CloudFoundry mean when they say that they "support the Grails framework"?

What is meant by this is that you can take a WAR file produced by Grails and run it on CloudFoundry without any additional work.

The CloudFoundry system uses build packs to handle the process of taking your application (i.e. your Grails WAR file) and preparing it to run.  As I mentioned above, this usually involves installing and configuring some sort of server.  In the case of Java / Grails, it involves setting up Apache Tomcat and configuring it to run your application (Note, if you don't like the way it's configured by default, you can customize or create your own build pack to configure it exactly the way you like).

CloudFoundry supports Grails and other JVM based languages because it can take those applications and automatically install, configure and run them.